# Integrals on unlimited sets

Tags: integration, analysis

How do you evaluate this expression
$$
\left| \int_{1}^{\infty} 1 \; dx - \int_{1}^{\infty} 1 \; dx \right| \quad ?
$$
Using improper integral definition, this should be an indeterminate $\infty - \infty$ form.

In general, if we integrate on a generic set $A$, when evaluating 
$$
\left| \int_{A} f \; dx - \int_{A} g \; dx \right|,
$$
should we make sure that it is not an indeterminate form?

ADDED: probably, in the first case, rules of limits allow to affirm that that difference is $0$. In the second, if improper integrals appears, we can do the same having a well defined result.

Comment: Yes, else it's undefined.

Comment: @Dror: What do you mean? This has a precise meaning, you have the absolute value of a difference of 2 numbers. You can't take a difference of $\infty$ and $\infty$ and so the whole expression is undefined.

Comment: I agree that it's undefined. It seems that Dror is thinking of the identity $\int_A (f-g)\,dx = \int_A f\,dx - \int_A g\,dx$ and suggesting that we change any expression of the latter type into an expression of the former type. However, the identity in question only holds when both integrals on the right-hand side exist! so using it when they don't is quite suspicious.

Comment: Note that using the change of variables $y=x+1$, we have $\int_1^\infty 1\,dx = \int_2^\infty 1\,dy$ (which is equal to $\int_2^\infty 1\,dx$, of course, since renaming the variable doesn't change anything). Hence $\int_1^\infty 1\,dx-\int_1^\infty 1\,dx = \int_1^\infty 1\,dx-\int_2^\infty 1\,dx = \int_1^2 1\,dx = 1$. Or is it $-1$...? - This is exactly why indeterminate forms really are indeterminate: trying to combine them using "natural" rules yields different answers depending on how you go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot evaluate that expression, for $\infty - \infty$ makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

Improper integrals of these types are defined in the following way.
$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx=\lim\ _{b\rightarrow+\infty}\int_a^bf(x)dx $ assuming $f$ in integrate on $[a,+\infty)$ In your case the answer is zero.if we agree that $\int f+g=\int f+\int g$. Basically infinities cancel each other out.For more about improper integrals check the link out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral
If we wanted to talk generic case weed would have to know about measure theory . Please see the awesome Wikipedia link

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x$ is undefined.

Comment: we want to have our definitions such that bigger class of functions converge. let me give you an example :compare graphs of $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ then the difference  gets larger and larger. Now compare that to situation $f(x)=g(x)=x$.Now if $\int_1^\infty 1dx$ is not even defined then what we are talking about?

Comment: You are not taking difference of functions, you are taking difference of integrals.